# How to insert this php instruction into printf result?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new in PHP World and I customizing a WordPress template.

I have the following function in a php file:

```
function admired_posted_on() {
    printf( __( '<span class="sep">Posted on </span>
                 <a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark">
                    <time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s" pubdate>%4$s</time>

                 </a>

                 <span>BLABLA</span>
                 <span class="by-author"> 
                    <span class="sep"> by bla</span> 
                    <span class="author vcard">
                        <a class="url fn n" href="%5$s" title="%6$s" rel="author">%7$s</a>

                    </span>

                 </span>
                 ', 'admired' ),

    esc_url( get_permalink() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() ),
    esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
    sprintf( esc_attr__( 'View all posts by %s', 'admired' ), get_the_author() ),
    esc_html( get_the_author() )
    );
    }
```

Now, I have to insert inside the **printf** body the following php code into the **BLABLA** tag instead of "BLABLA" text. This is the php code that I have to insert:

```
<?php echo '(' . get_PostViews(get_the_ID()) . ')'; ?>
```

If I insert ithis row into the previous span tag go into error.

The get_PostViews(get_the_ID()) return an integer that have to be show in that span

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

If there are single quotes `'` in a string which is enclosed with single quotes you will have to escape that quotes. Like this (note the `\'`):

```
$string = '<span class="sep">Posted on <?php echo \'(\' . get_PostViews(get_the_ID()) . \')\'; ?></span>... more content ....';
```

But in your example the following solution might be simpler:

```
$string = '<span class="sep">Posted on (<?php echo get_PostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>)</span>... more content ....';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method to your function.

```
function admired_posted_on() {
    printf( __( '<span class="sep">Posted on </span>
                 <a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark">
                    <time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s" pubdate>%4$s</time>
                 </a>
                 <span>%5$s</span>
                 <span class="by-author"> 
                    <span class="sep"> by bla</span> 
                    <span class="author vcard">
                        <a class="url fn n" href="%6$s" title="%7$s" rel="author">%8$s</a>
                    </span>
                 </span>
                 ', 'admired' ),

    esc_url( get_permalink() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() ),
    get_PostViews(get_the_ID()),
    esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
    sprintf( esc_attr__( 'View all posts by %s', 'admired' ), get_the_author() ),
    esc_html( get_the_author() )
    );
}
```

**Additional Answer:**

To answer your question, this might be easier if you see it on a single row.

```
printf('First Var: %1$s | Second Var: %2$s | Third Var: %3$s', $firstvar, $secondvar, $thirdvar);
```

The %1$s are placeholders for the proceeding variables that are listed after the quoted text.

This same information can be shown in the same way but just spaced differently referred to the original post

```
printf('First Var: %1$s | Second Var: %2$s | Third Var: %3$s', 
    $firstvar, 
    $secondvar, 
    $thirdvar
);
```

And adding the Underscore infront of the text allows the text to be translated to multiple languages (which is a function inside of Wordpress) and the comma with 'admired' just indicates the admired theme identifier which is where it will look for a translation method.

```
printf(__('First Var: %1$s | Second Var: %2$s | Third Var: %3$s', 'admired'), 
    $firstvar, 
    $secondvar, 
    $thirdvar
);
```

Comment: Ok, I have try your code and seems work well but I can not understand how it works: I say that you have add this line next to the date link: <span>%5$s</span> I think that %5$s it's a placeholdert that will be replaced by the concrete value (the number of person that have read the article returned by the function). I also say that you have insert the call of get_PostViews() function after the closure of the printf(). I thinkt that when the get_PostViews(get_the_ID()) return the value, this value is substituted to the placeholder %5$s (is it right)?

Comment: If it is right can explain me how the get_PostViews() returned value is associate to the %5$s placeholder?

Maybe are they in ascending order? So the first placeholder is replaced by the returned value of the first declared function and so on?

Tnx

Comment: I went ahead and added answers to your question.

Comment: And to answer, Yes the variables after the text is in ascending order.  Also to answer your first question, please review the amount of open/close brackets as the brackets do not finish closing the printf() after the 'admired') but rather after all the variables.